# Use python to parse values from ping output into csv

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, csv

I wrote a code using RE to look for "time=" and save the following value in a string. Then I use the csv.writer attribute writerow, but each number is interpreted as a column, and this gives me trouble later. Unfortunately there is no 'writecolumn' attribute. Should I save the values as an array instead of a string and write every row separately?

```
import re
import csv
inputfile = open("ping.txt")
teststring = inputfile.read()
values = re.findall(r'time=(\d+.\d+)', teststring)
with open('parsed_ping.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(values)
```

EDIT: I understood that "values" is already a list. I tried to iterate it and write a row for each item with

```
for item in values:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

Now i get a space after each character, like

```
4 6 . 6
4 7 . 7
```

EDIT2: The spaces are the delimiters. If i change the delimiter to comma, i get commas between digits. I just don't get why he's interpreting each digit as a separate column.

Comment: Can you better describe what is the expected format for the output?

Comment: I would simply like a csv file with a single column containing all the parsed numbers.

Comment: is that 'ping.txt' an output of a packet sniffer? if so, there are tools which could make your further parsing easier, in case you do not just want to extract the timestamp.

Comment: CSV with one column? ...

Comment: I agree that CSV with one column is a stretch of the concept itself, but I thought of this as a first step, that I could later improve including other data.

Answer (score 2):

If your `csv` file only contains one column, it's not really a "comma-separated file" anymore, is it?

Just write the list to the file directly:

```
import re
inputfile = open("ping.txt")
teststring = inputfile.read()
values = re.findall(r'time=(\d+\.\d+)', teststring)
with open('parsed_ping.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write("\n".join(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. I just needed to use square brackets in the writer.

```
for item in values:
    writer.writerow([item])
```

This gives me the correct output.